# partial derivatives and a $(u,v)=(1,1)$ neighbourhoods

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

I'm currently working through the problem:

*In a neighbourhood of $(u,v)=(1,1)$; show that the system:*

$$
\begin{cases}
x=u+\ln(v)  \\
y = v-\ln(u) \\
z=2u+v
\end{cases}
$$

*defines a function $z=z(x,y)$ and find the partial derivatives $z'_{x}$ and $z'_{y}$*

Now I know I am supposed to use the implicit function theorem in some way, but I'm used to starting with a system of equations like:

**Example:**
$$
\begin{cases}
F(x,y,u,v) = x^2 -y^2-2u=0  \\
G(x,y,u,v) = xy -v-u=0 
\end{cases}
$$

My gut instinct is telling me to use some substitution to see if I can't tease out $z=z(x,y)$ but I don't think it is that simple.

I guess I'm looking for a solid first step (or two steps) to get me started on tackling a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

Given the system, you can "manually unroll" the implicit function theorem.

You can always differentiate the first two equations withe respect to $x$ and $y$ - you will get $4$ equations for four variables $u'_x$, $u'_y$, $v'_x$, and $v'_y$. This will give the expressions for these derivatives in terms of $u$ and $v$.

After that, you will need to find values of $u$ and $v$ corresponding to $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Finally, $z'_x = 2u'_x+v'_x$ and similarly for $z'_y$.

Comment: So just to clarify, the term $u'_{x}=\delta u/\delta x$ (and so on for the others...)

Comment: I guess I'm still a little bit stuck on what to do after finding $u'_{x},u'_{y},v'_{x},v'_{y}$

Comment: @Sprawk48 can you find $u$ and $v$ such that $x=1$ and $y=1$?

Comment: So, If i understand right $u'_x = 1, \ u'_y=-e^v e^{-y}, \ v'_x = e^x e^{-u}, \ v'_y = 1$, and If I use the first two equations from the original system, I think I get $(u,v) =(1,1)$ for $(x,y)=(1,1)$